# Force upper function to return

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm coding discord bot and want to add function that checks if command sender is admin and if he's not, forcing upper function to return.

For example:

```
admins = [# List with users that are admins]

def inspect(ctx):
    if ctx.author not in admins:
        ctx.send('You are not an admin.')
        # Make say_hi() stop working
    else:
        pass

@bot.command()
async def say_hi(ctx, *text):
    inspect(ctx)
    await ctx.send('Greetings, my Lord.')
```

As I understand, in this situation it's impssible to use decorators because we couldn't acess `ctx` needed to proceed.

I could do something like this:

```
admins = [# List with users that are admins]

def inspect(ctx):
    if ctx.author not in admins:
        ctx.send('You are not an admin.')
        return True
    else:
        return False

@bot.command()
async def say_hi(ctx, *text):
    if inspect(ctx):
        return
    await ctx.send('Greetings, my Lord.')
```

But if possible, I'd like to simplify the code to single function.

Comment: You could return a boolean from `inspect` indicating if the function can/should continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to check this and not to develop a function for yourself you can use this two method:

1.

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def testcommand(ctx:commands.Context):
    ...
```

2. 

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_role
@bot.command()
@has_role(ROLE_NAME)
async def testcommand2(ctx:commands.Context):
    ...
```

If you would like to stick whit your method, here is a corrected version of it:

```
admins = [THE_ID_OF_THE_ADMIN]

def inspect(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id in admins

@bot.command()
async def say_hi(ctx:commands.Context, *text):
    if inspect(ctx):
        await ctx.send('Greetings, my Lord.')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not admin")
```

In this case, save the admins id into the list and check for that.

Comment: Indeed, has_role is the best option for my purposes, I will use this decorator. But forcing parent functions to return something is still not possible?

Comment: I'll cover it in my other answer

Answer (score 0):

Replying to your comment if what you mean is that you want to prevent the function from executing when the condition is false, you can do that:

1.

```
admins = [ID]

def inspect(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id in admins

@bot.command()
async def sayhi(ctx:commands.Context, *text):
    if not inspect(ctx):
        raise Exception(f"{ctx.author} who is not an admin, tried to use the command")
    else:
        await ctx.send('Greetings, my Lord.')
```

This will cause an error in the console, but will not stop the whole bot. It returns your custom message as an Exception

2.

```
admins = [ID]
    
    def inspect(ctx):
        return ctx.author.id in admins

@bot.command()
async def sayhi(ctx:commands.Context, *text):
    if not inspect(ctx):
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send('Greetings, my Lord.')
```

And this second one is just simply returns nothing. The function will stop whenever someone whitout admin permission tries to execute it.